# Change table border upon hover

Tags: html, css, css-tables

### EDIT

To be clearer, the below is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

---

I'm trying to create a table where each row has a single pixel border with a radius (mimicking a collapsed border style). Upon hovering over a row, I'd like the selected row's border to change colour. I've almost achieved this with the following code, but upon hovering over a row, the following row drops down 1px to make room for the hover border.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-style: solid none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

td:first-child {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

td:last-child {
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

tr:hover {
    /*background-color: #cad6ed;*/
}

tr:hover td {
    border: 1px solid #12A0F8;
    border-style: solid none;
    padding: 10px;
}

tr:hover td:first-child {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

tr:hover td:last-child {
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a better approach to this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the border on the element before hovering as well, you can make the colour transparent if need to. It jumps because you are adding a new border on hover

Comment: row shift down because when you hover it you add a border bottom :1px, when it's not hover this border is set to 0px

Comment: @Huangism but surely that will make the table row 1px larger than it needs to be?

Comment: The added image helps tremendously.

Comment: Will your setup always be three table rows? Or will it vary?

Comment: It will always vary.

Comment: When you output the markup for the table, how do you do it? Is it some sort of programmable loop. Can you change/add to the markup? If so, I can get my solution to work for you without changing the display property of the tr.

Comment: @disinfor It's created dynamically via JSON via an API, but yes, the markup can change, as long as it's still valid.

Comment: @chut319 ok, my answer has been updated. Keeps `tr` display the same, but uses CSS `var()`. In your loop you should be able to add the `style=""` and then for each iteration, increase the number but prefix it with the `-` (negative) value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated better solution**

Don't know why I didn't tackle the core issue from the start but your main issue was the item below was getting pushed down, well you can target the next item and set the border top to none

```
tr:hover + tr td {
    border-top: none;
}
```

The rest of your original code remains intact

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-style: solid none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

tr:hover + tr td {
    border-top: none;
}

td:first-child {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

td:last-child {
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

tr:hover {
    /*background-color: #cad6ed;*/
}

tr:hover td {
    border: 1px solid #12A0F8;
    border-style: solid none;
    padding: 10px;
}

tr:hover td:first-child {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

tr:hover td:last-child {
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td><td>Two dfds</td><td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Old answer

You can do it by setting the `tr` to display block. I used margin-top -1px to hide the extra border. To simplify things, I removed border from td and just put it on the `tr` since you don't have borders in between tds anyway

The z-index on hover makes the hovered item popup with the border

I put the negative margin on all tr but the first, you could probably get away with it on all `tr`s

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

tr {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

tr:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: -1px;
}

tr:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I must tell you that, if your items in the td are not the same width, this will break their alignment, since tr are display block

Comment: Ah! Alignment will be an issue then as the cell content will differ between rows. Is there any way you can think to mitigate this?

Comment: @chut319 can your html change?

Comment: @Huangism Yes, as long as it's valid markup, it's flexible.

Comment: @chut319 seems all you needed is one extra rule to make your original code work, answer is updated

Comment: @Huangism how did we all overthink this?!

Comment: @Huangism - this is brilliant. Works perfectly. Thank you so very much.

Comment: @disinfor probably because we all try to over complicate things before simplifying them

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Includes CSS `var()` and updating the HTML markup to include that var.

You need to remove the `border-width` property on hover and just use `border-color` You also need to overlap the `tr` elements so the border appears to be one pixel.

I've updated the answer to use `z-index` and a negative `top` value. Caveat this will only work with three `tr` elements, if you need a dynamic solution, the answer can be updated based on how you generate the table.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tr {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  top: var(--rowCount);
}

td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-style: solid none;
  padding: 10px;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

tr:hover {
  /*background-color: #cad6ed;*/
  z-index: 5;
}

tr:hover td {
  border-color: #12A0F8;
  border-style: solid none;
  padding: 10px;
}

tr:hover td:first-child {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

tr:hover td:last-child {
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style="--rowCount: 0px">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="--rowCount: -1px">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="--rowCount: -2px">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="--rowCount: -3px">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/nhp3o8xw/31/

Comment: It's correct but in your solution the border bottom it's not colored

Comment: There's no mention in the OP about the bottom border. Just changing the border's color on hover. I can update my answer if that's the case.

Comment: I guess  the OP need the border bottom. :)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't explicit enough but yes, I need the bottom border too. Thank you.

Comment: Updated answer and fiddle to include bottom border on hover.

Comment: @disinfor thanks for this, but I need the bottom-border to be present with and without a hover.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In your original CSS, you specifically set the bottom-border to not be visible using `border-bottom: 0`

Comment: @chut319 I've updated my answer to get closer to what you want, but there are the caveats mentioned.

Comment: @disinfor Thank you, I really appreciate your help with this. Your solution is perfect, but it needs to be for a dynamic amount of rows.

Comment: @disinfor - this is fantastic, thank you - I really appreciate your help. I wish I could also mark this as a correct answer, but Huangism's answer allowed me to do what I needed with a little less mark-up/changes.

Comment: Agreed! Huanguism's answer is the best route to go. We all overthought this! Ha!

Answer (score 0):

Remove border-bottom: 0; in td tag

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  z-index:0;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-style: solid none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

tr:hover td{
  border-color: #12A0F8;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #12A0F8;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but upon hovering I'm getting an inconsistent border, sometimes black, sometimes blue.

Comment: now change the code; tr:hover td{
      border-color: #12A0F8;
      border-bottom: solid 1px #12A0F8;
      padding-bottom: 9px;
    }

Comment: Thank you - seems to work well, but I've already been given an alternative solution which works for me. Thanks for your help though.